# Trying to Delete last name starting with Z or z in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-delete

My task is to delete any faculty member whos name starts with Z or z. I have tried some code that I have been researching but am having trouble making it work. The following is the code for creating the table, inserting into the table, and finally my attempt to delete the entry:

```
CREATE TABLE Faculty (
FacultyID int primary key,
FirstName varchar(30),
LastName varchar(30),
EMail varchar(60),
BirthDate DATE,
Numbr_Courses int
);

insert into Faculty 
values (10579, 'John','Spelling','jspelling@faculty.umuc.edu','1983-06-26','5'); 

insert into Faculty 
values (10894, 'Ron','Danning','rdanning@faculty.umuc.edu','1976-06-12','4');

insert into Faculty 
values (23487, 'Blair','Davidson','bdavidson@faculty.umuc.edu','1977-08-27','2'); 

insert into Faculty 
values (13456, 'David','Burtner','dburtner@faculty.umuc.edu','1967-11-04','3');

insert into Faculty 
values (78546, 'Jessica','Dawn','jdawn@faculty.umuc.edu','1973-05-28','3');

insert into Faculty 
values (23564, 'Randy','Zilman','rgilman@faculty.umuc.edu','1975-10-04','3');

insert into Faculty 
values (85462, 'Carol','Lily','clily@faculty.umuc.edu','1954-07-16','3');  

insert into Faculty 
values (45126, 'Jason','Borne','jborne@faculty.umuc.edu','1963-01-26','4');

insert into Faculty 
values (65894, 'Tom','Cruise','tcruise@faculty.umuc.edu','1965-08-01','3'); 

insert into Faculty 
values (56451, 'Michael','Jordan','mjordan@faculty.umuc.edu','1959-12-26','3');

DELETE FROM Faculty WHERE LastName='Z%'
```

I thought the final statement would delete the code but it doesn't delete it it just stays the same. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

```
DELETE FROM Faculty WHERE LastName LIKE 'Z%'
```

While using wildcard % you need to use LIKE instead of =.